# How can I get ref text when I have many refs in kivy label?

Tags: python, label, kivy, ref

Please help.
I have many refs in label and when user click on first ref how can i get ref text on main.py? 
I need python method which can get this ref text.

```
Label:
     markup: True
     text: "[ref=first ref]First ref[/ref] ,[ref=second ref]Second ref[/ref]"
     on_ref_press: # here I need method that can return ref.text
```

Answer (score 2):

All the arguments passed to the event handler are available in kv via the `args` variable. The arguments to the `on_ref_press` handler are `instance, refvalue`. So, for example:

```
Label:
    markup: True
    text: "[ref=first ref]First ref[/ref] ,[ref=second ref]Second ref[/ref]"
    on_ref_press: print args[1]
```

will cause `first ref` to be printed when the "First ref" text is clicked, and `second ref` will be printed when the "Second ref" text is clicked.